# "Waiting for table metadata lock" on Aurora MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-web-services, jpa

I investigate one problem on the database (Aurora MySQL 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.0).
In my AWS service, we change the database structure automatically through the java code, namely through spring (**schema.sql + spring.sql.init.mode=always**). Examples: Create table if exist, alter table, etc.
And after some time, I get a DB "*waiting for table metadata lock*" error (photo below), which leads to the fall of the kubernetes pod (above limit CPU usage).
There is the same service working with GCP (Big Query) doing the same auto-configuration through the same piece of code and there is no such problem.

Schema.sql file

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS job_detail (
  job_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  created_by varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  dataflow_id varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  periodic_tasks longtext,
  error_details longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  executed_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  failed_records longtext,
  total_records int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  created_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_by varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  job_status varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  job_summary longtext,
  job_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  project_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (job_id)
);

ALTER TABLE  job_detail CHANGE COLUMN created_by created_by VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  job_detail CHANGE COLUMN updated_by updated_by VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

[Photo of queries logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwUIM.png)

Comment: What is your Aurora instance type?   So we can determine available RAM and VCPU's? Could you also post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; to go with your 50+ AAS graph so we can see what is running, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck the instance type is db.t4g.medium

Comment: @WilsonHauck   https://notepad.ltd/dczrzmms it is the result of  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST

Comment: The SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; indicates 64 of 68 processes are sleeping.  Sometimes for hours (which is abnormal).  Will be out of office until Friday noon.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, the result of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE \"%connect%\" is https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.54c5533e4e0346cebe1f6f6404b5802e&right=local.regome

Comment: Please provide your code used to 'connect','process','close' the connection. I suspect the 'close' is being missed. 

View profile for contact info.